# A Problem occurred starting process 'command '../../node_modules/hermesvm/win64-bin/hermes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, facebook, react-native-hermes

When i try to debug using the command `react-native run-android --variant=betaDebug --appIdSuffix=prod` it works perfectly fine. but when i tried to release a build using `./gradlew assembleBetaRelease` this happens

```
Execution failed for task ':app:bundlereleasejsandassets'. > a problem occurred starting process 'command '../../node_modules/hermesvm/win64-bin/hermes
```

I tried making some changes in fixing the path, but still same error

```
project.ext.react = [
...some options...
enableHermes: true,
hermesCommand: "../../node_modules/hermesvm/%OS-BIN%/hermes"]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWB6F.png)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?